# Bootstrap Carousel - caption below the image without effecting the height of the control?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I make the carousel caption below the image but **without** effecting the height of the carousel-control?

Below is my css to move the caption below the image:

```
.carousel-caption {
    position: relative;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
}
```

Result:
[image]

As you can see the carousel-control is now **longer**. How can I fix this? Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JQuery would be the way to go I believe.

Take a look at: http://www.bootply.com/wngSniePbu

Only requires a small amount of JQuery and one additional CSS class.